# @RestController - Collection issue

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, swagger, jhipster

I am implementing a spring boot application using @RestController w/ Angular.js client and I want to create/update a Group with one or multiple Users (as children). This does not work with multiple users.

Model Signature:

```
Grp {
externalId (string, optional),
grpOwner (User, optional),
grpTxt (string, optional),
users (Array[User], optional)
}

User {
externalId (string, optional),
username (string, optional)
}
```

grp.json (both users exist in database)

```
{
  "externalId": "G0000001",
  "users": [
    {
      "username": "admin"
    },
    {
      "username": "system"
    }
  ]
})
```

When trying to create/update one Group w/ multiple users, only the first one is taken into consideration. Actually, when debugging the Java part. Any idea?

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Grp> updateGrp(@RequestBody Grp grp) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to update Grp : {}", grp);
        // Check if the group has been created
        Optional<Grp> oGrp = gDao.findOneByExternalIdAndGrpOwner(grp.getExternalId(), this.getCurrentUser());
        if (oGrp.isPresent()) {
            Grp mGrp = oGrp.get();
            this.merge(mGrp, grp);          
            Grp result = gDao.save(mGrp);
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert("grp", grp.getExternalId().toString()))
                .body(result);

        }
        return createGrp(grp);
    }
```

Trace:

```
2016-07-06 11:29:12.563 DEBUG 3216 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing PUT request for [/api/grps]
2016-07-06 11:29:12.566 DEBUG 3216 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /api/grps
2016-07-06 11:29:12.567 DEBUG 3216 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.coopyrightcode.common.domain.Grp> com.coopyrightcode.common.web.rest.GrpResource.updateGrp(com.coopyrightcode.common.domain.Grp) throws java.net.URISyntaxException]
2016-07-06 11:29:12.604 DEBUG 3216 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Read [class com.coopyrightcode.common.domain.Grp] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" with [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@4982ce48]
2016-07-06 11:29:12.613 DEBUG 3216 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.c.common.aop.logging.LoggingAspect     : Enter: com.coopyrightcode.common.web.rest.GrpResource.updateGrp() with argument[s] = [Grp [grpTxt=null, grpOwner=null, users=[User [username=admin, password=null, fName=null, lName=null, email=null, activated=false, langKey=null, appKey=63d71c52-95cd-43db-9, resetKey=3dfaf9f7-b46d-4daf-9, resetDate=null, usrAccountNonLocked=true, usrAccountNonExpired=true, usrCredentialsNonExpired=true, usrBio=null, usrMobile=null, usrPhone=null, usrPics=null, usrReferent=null, usrCtrId=null]]]]
2016-07-06 11:29:12.613 DEBUG 3216 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.c.common.web.rest.PortfolioResource    : REST request to update Grp : Grp [grpTxt=null, grpOwner=null, users=[User [username=admin, password=null, fName=null, lName=null, email=null, activated=false, langKey=null, appKey=63d71c52-95cd-43db-9, resetKey=3dfaf9f7-b46d-4daf-9, resetDate=null, usrAccountNonLocked=true, usrAccountNonExpired=true, usrCredentialsNonExpired=true, usrBio=null, usrMobile=null, usrPhone=null, usrPics=null, usrReferent=null, usrCtrId=null]]]
```

Comment: try to mark the `users` field with a Jackson annotation like `@JsonProperty("users")`

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not successful. Is there a possibility to debug the json mapper? I have tried to set some breakpoints in package org.springframework.http.converter.json w/o any success.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the json mapper? Does the received *Grp* object contain the users array as expected if you debug it. What does this.merge do?

Comment: I have updated the post with a trace. Grp contains one element while sending 2 elements on client side.

Comment: @JackAdmin, I assume `users` field is `private` one. If to set this to `public` it  would work. But however, it doesn't solve the problem:( Btw, do you have setters&getters? And both constructors as well? (default+full one)

Comment: Don't know about json mapper debugging, never did this before. But you can drop into controller return in debug mode, possible will do the trick